# Show window on multiple Desktops

Tags: windows-7, windows, user-accounts, user-interface

What I want to do:

I usually log in with multiple accounts simultaniously. Say, I have my personal account and my work account and I leave my personal user logged in while I'm working. However I'd like to have my browser window (started from my personal account) available in my work account.

I've heard this is possible in linux somehow, but I could't find a way for windows.

Comment: This is not possible with Windows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is called "**Multiseat**" and there's two kind of solution for this: commercial solutions and "tweaks" explaining how to enable concurrent sessions in Windows 7 ... the tweaks are obviously not guaranteed and possibly illegal with the current Microsoft license. So the best is to look for a commercial one, right?

Check this Wikipedia article to start your research for the best option for you:

[Multiseat configuration](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration)

Comment: that looks good! Have to check my license though...

Answer (score 2):

Find Internet Explorer in the All Programs menu, hold down the Shift key and right click the IE icon, choose 'Run as different user'

This should allow you to run two seperate instances of IE from the same account. See [here](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/419-run-different-user.html) for step by step with pics.

Comment: Yes, two different instances, I want it to be the same instance

Comment: that's the only way it will work, there is no way to bring a window from a seperate user session into another user session, afaik. I'm curious though, why would this not work for your use?

Comment: It would just be a "convenience feature" for me. If I switch around, say in my break, I'd still have the same Browser session.

Comment: chrome allows multiple accounts in the same browswer session, firefox might also have this, not sure. IE doesn't. What you are describing is a very odd situation for a work machine though. Just saying.