# Windows Multiple Desktop - different users active at same time

Tags: windows, virtual-machine, virtual-desktop, multiple-users, multiple-desktop

I couldn't see any specific answer so asking the community directly.

Using the "Windows Multiple Desktop Feature" (see picture linked below in case of ambiguity) can I have one Windows User (or MS Windows Account) logged in on one desktop, and another User (or MS account) logged into another?

If different users accounts is a limitation of this functionality, could anyone suggest the simplest tutorials/software to achieve this is a virtual desktop environment?

Screen shot of Multiple Desktop User launchpad access screen

[image: Screen shot of Multiple Desktop User launchpad access screen]

Comment: No, you cannot. I don't think there is a piece of software that will allow you to do that. But switching users in Windows is quite fast nowadays if both are already active and you have an SSD.

Comment: this is not possible without terminal services, which Microsoft has locked down for client OSes, and charges extra for with Server OSes. people have been trying to do this since 2002 or so, when XP introduced the limitation (it was not present in Win2k), and yet no meaningful solutions have been found. consider Windows clients to be single-user systems. MS's interest is in making sure people buy windows server, and CALs for concurrent access.

Answer (score 3):

You can't use and see multiple users on a desktop at once, it'll violate security rules. You can use [Fast User Switching](https://www.technipages.com/windows-10-enable-or-disable-fast-user-switching) though, and just a [simple click](https://beebom.com/best-ways-to-switch-users-windows-10/) will switch you to the other user account (after a quick login of course, which can be accelerated even more with Windows Hello biometric login with finger or face), and lock the current user. This is true even for Windows server, you aren't allowed to see the other users' environments

But if you have multiple monitors you can use multiple users concurrently. This is called [multiseat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiseat_configuration) and has nothing to do with virtual desktops. You can probably fake the multiple monitors with a [KVM switch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KVM_switch), but you still need special software to enable multiseat feature. See

- [Setting up a multiseat configuration](https://superuser.com/q/29879/241386)
- [Show window on multiple Desktops](https://superuser.com/q/458639/241386)
- [How do I share a single computer among different users?](https://superuser.com/q/192709/241386)
- [Can two users simultaneously share one pc](https://superuser.com/q/106842/241386)
- [multiseat](/questions/tagged/multiseat)
- [How to Split One Windows PC Between Two People With Multiseat Software](https://www.makeuseof.com/split-one-windows-pc-between-two-people-multiseat/)

---

The simpler solution is to use virtual machines. Just bind separate monitors and input devices to separate virtual machines and you can use them in parallel, because they're technically separate machines and can be used simultaneously

Answer (score 0):

Multiple simultaneous users on the same desktop: It seems it is possible with this 3rd party software called MouseMux. Only found this site now, but it looks promising, and while still in beta it's free to use. https://mousemux.com/

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1139733)

Answer (score 0):

You could use remote desktop if you're willing to hack with your system:

1. Install [rdwrap](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap) this is a small open source tool that will enable rdp with multiple connections on windows desktop. Some virus scanners will flag it as a virus because it messes with system files. This is a bit hackish and possibly a violation of the Windows EULA. so only do this if you're willing to go down this road. [Install tutorial for Windows 11](https://%20https://www.anyviewer.com/how-to/open-multiple-remote-desktop-connections-0007.html.).
2. Then enable Remote Desktop in Windows and enable it for the users you want to use it with.
3. Use a rdp client (I recommend [PRemoteM](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/premotem-mstsc-remote-desktop/9PNMNF92JNFP?hl=en-us&gl=us)) to connect to 127.0.0.2 (127.0.0.1 will not work) and login with the user and password. This will give you a remote desktop connection.

An alternative would be to use a VM.

Here is the discussion about the legality for reference: [github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/issues/26](https://github.com/stascorp/rdpwrap/issues/26).

IMHO the chance of you getting in trouble for this is marginal but it might be an issue if you're using company equipment and with insurances.

Comment: A very good point - good enough that it should be in the actual answer. I just put it there, so you can delete the comment :-)